# Display 2 modal windows with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

I want to display 2 modal windows containing HTML content with jQuery.
But second modal window must be within the first.

So, here is main page, when I click link it opens first modal window, and then when I click a link in this modal window in opens second modal window.

I tried to do this with [qTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/demos/effects/modal), but I can't make second modal window. 
I will be appreciate if somebody tells me how can I realize this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me this sounds like an ui failure - modals within modals are not healthy for a user interface, and thus modal frameworks rarely support it.

If i was you I'd find another design rather than solve this problem programatically

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend the [jQuery UI Modal Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/), it should allow having two dialogs open at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

qTip allows to open modal in modal.
Something is going wrong with your code.
Post it here and i can give you a solution!